# Get model objects in model of same model

Tags: django, model

I had a lot of car brands but not so many cars. I need to get only car brands which has cars.

Problem is how to call this CarForRent.objects.all() in CarForRent model?

Here is how I'm trying to do this:

```
     # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
        from __future__ import unicode_literals
        from django.contrib.auth.models import User
        from django.db import models

        from information.models import CarBrand, CarModel, City


        class CarForRent(models.Model):
            owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
            brand = models.ForeignKey(CarBrand)
            model = models.ForeignKey(CarModel)
            years = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=CAR_YEAR_CHOICES)
            consumption = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
            body_type = models.CharField(max_length=21, choices=BODY_TYPE_CHOICES)
            fuel_type = models.CharField(max_length=21, choices=FUEL_TYPE_CHOICES)
            transmission_type = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=TRANSMISSION_TYPE_CHOICES)
            doors = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=DOOR_TYPE_CHOICES)
            air_conditioner = models.BooleanField(default=True)

            def get_active_car_brands(self):
                brands = []
                active_brands = []
  ---------->   for car in CarForRent.objects.all(): <--------- problem
                    brands.append(car.brand)
                for brand in brands:
                    active_brands.append(CarBrand.objects.get(id=brand))
                return active_brands
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that would generally be solved at the form level.

The biggest roadblock right now is that there is no logic shown that shows what car models belong to what car brands. [Django Smart Selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects) is often used to provide nested foreign key relations.

If that was properly set up and there was a CarModel model that was related to a brand, we could easily override the queryset provided to a modelform for brands. Take this example of a generic `ModelForm`; we will set the queryset in an overriden `__init__` method.

```
from django import forms
from myapp.models import CarsForRent

class CarsForRentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = CarsForRent
    exclude = [] # or pass a list/tuple of field name string in a 'fields' parameter
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CarsForRentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # access object through self.instance...
        self.fields['brand'].queryset = CarBrand.objects.filter(model__set__count__gt=0) # model__set represents the related_name parameter providen for CarModel's FK relation to CarBrand
```

Without seeing any way to tell what car models belong to which car brands, there is no way to perform an action like this. Feel free to add to the question if this logic is in place.